# How to Stop a Conditional Formatting once it work?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

How would I stop a conditional formatting once it passes the number I originally wanted it to. I still want to keep the conditional formatting but heres an example

Bounce SPOT = 720 TSLA CURRENTLY= 738.If it drops to 720 and it touches I want it to stop using the conditional formatting if it gets passed 718.50

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1IhC.png)

Comment: You can't do that with conditional formatting. It needs VBA.

Comment: can you please demonstrate the desired outcome (format) if the value is above target, equals or under the target but still greater than the bottom line, and under the bottom line? I am not 100% clear on what you want to achieve.